# What is the problem with empirical priors?

Tags: bayesian, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

In literature I sometimes stumple upon the remark, that choosing priors that depend on the data itself  (for example Zellners g-prior) can be criticized from a theoretical point of view. Where exactly is the problem if the prior is not chosen independent from the data?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally, informative priors are typically viewed as your information about parameters (or hypotheses) **before** seeing the data. So any data-based prior is violating the [likelihood principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_principle) since evidence from the sample is coming through the likelihood function and the prior.

Answer (score 9):

The $p$-values are wrong. Take a simple example. Test whether a population mean $\mu$ is equal to a particular value $\mu_0$ or not. Suppose the sample mean $\bar x$ is greater than $\mu_0$. Then it would be simply wrong to let the data guide you into testing only a one-sided alternative. Your $p$-value will be half of what it should be.

And just to be clear: The restriction $\mu \ge \mu_0$ implied by the one-sided alternative is a kind of empirical prior. (It throws away half of the possible values for $\mu$ *a priori*.)

Comment: Am astounded, flabbergasted and delighted that you are using a frequentist framework to illustrate a Bayesean concept.

Comment: Same. The first sentence made me go "what the hell?"

Comment: I agree, this is an interesting way of starting a conversation in a Bayesian context. But do I understand it correct that this intuitive explanation also just describes a violation of the likelihood principle as @jaradniemi pointed out in his answer?

Comment: @Alexis a frequentist with domain expertise is a Bayesian in denial

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Haha, not quite sure if I understand what you're trying to say. Is that a tongue-in-cheek way of saying a frequentist with domain expertise can't exist? :P

Comment: @Mehrdad not at all. But if you apply domain expertise to a problem, you're implicitly bringing a prior into the model selection process

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Ohh, I see now -- I thought by "domain expertise" you were referring to their statistical skills, never mind!