# Resampling as prior distribution?

Tags: regression, bayesian, prior, small-sample, resampling

Suppose we've got a small dataset that we have no prior knowledge about and we're going to use linear regression on it. I have been wondering whether instead of fitting a normal OLS it would make sense to first estimate regression coefficients using jackknife/bootstrap and - if there is a difference between the resampled regression and OLS applied to the whole dataset - use the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the resampled models as the prior distribution to bayesian regression. Can I actually do that? Is my way of thinking correct or I'm not taking something into account?

Comment: I am not a Bayesian but isn't the prior supposed to be, well, prior?

Comment: @PeterFlom Yeah and the question is whether this information can be treated as a prior

Comment: How can it be prior, when you are getting it from the data?

Comment: @PeterFlom The idea is, that the values of the coefficients estimated by resampling aren't equal to coefficients estimated by MLE on that set of data. This leads to belief that the small sample size affects the MLE coefficients and the true coefficients are closer to the ones infered with resampling - but closer doesn't mean equal, which is why I thought about going bayesian.

Comment: no l, this is not acceptable. As noted by PF, the prior is something you fix before seeing the data.

Comment: What you are proposing is a feedback mechanism. Why do you want to do this? Why not simply run OLS?

Comment: @StephanKolassa A feedback mechanism? Because I'm interested in improving performance of regression on small datasets :) OLS is my starting point

Comment: If you are using an observation *twice*, first to derive a "prior" and then to derive a posterior, then you will get positive feedback. "Prior" in scare quotes, because as others are writing, it is not a prior if it depends on the very data you want to update it with later on. So: why not simply use OLS? Or conversely, why not iterate the process multiple times? I would recommend that you simulate some data, then try your approach on it - and iterate this loop *multiple* times. You will run into problems. Once you see these, you will understand why even a single iteration is problematic.

Comment: @Fatafim what you're describing is very similar to what's called [Empirical Bayes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/156927).